# plt.imshow(Z,norm=logNorm()) gives grey outline when Z=0

Tags: matplotlib, histogram, imshow

Sorry for no pictures, but this code reproduces the problem:

```
x=np.random.randn(1000)
y=np.random.randn(1000)
h,_,_=np.histogram2d(x,y)
plt.imshow(h, norm=LogNorm(), cmap=plt.cm.Greys)
```

I would expect a smooth white transition from very small values to 0 values, but there seems to be a blurred border I'd like to get rid of.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to be expected because values less or equal to zero are masked and then positive values are normalized. That might mean that `LogNorm` is not the best option for you, but if you insist on using it you can try adding the minimum positive value to the histogram. In your case it would be 1 but let's do it more general for, say, normed histograms.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

x = np.random.randn(1000)
y = np.random.randn(1000)
h, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x, y)
im = plt.imshow(h, norm=LogNorm(), cmap=plt.cm.Greys,
                interpolation='bilinear')
plt.colorbar(im)
```

[image: histogram1]

```
im = plt.imshow(h + np.min(h[h > 0]), norm=LogNorm(), cmap=plt.cm.Greys,
                interpolation='bilinear')
plt.colorbar(im)
```

[image]

Note that this change won't affect bilinear interpolation but might affect other interpolation algorithms. To ensure that interpolation is not affected you would have to create a custom subclass of `Normalize`.

The above figures were made using matplotlib 2.0.0rc1 which [applies color mapping after interpolation](http://matplotlib.org/2.0.0rc1/users/dflt_style_changes.html#colormapping-pipeline). If you use a previous version you will see even more artifacts in the first figure.

Comment: Hmm. What you have in your first picture would be fine, but it is not what I have.  Can't upload pictures from work but there is a dark grey line along the border between masked and unmasked bins that makes the whole graph unclear, especially with small bins.

Comment: @DanielForsman I've updated the answer to explain why what you see is even worse.